# Is there sense to be made for two-tailed T-test and OLS of two variables?

Tags: regression, t-test, least-squares, r-squared

Let's say we start off by generating 2 random uniform variables between 1 and 100

```
rv1=np.random.uniform(1,100,1000)
rv2=np.random.uniform(1,100,1000)
rv2=sm.add_constant(rv2)

sm.OLS(rv1, rv2).fit().summary()

                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.001
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                   0.06250
Date:                Thu, 27 Apr 2023   Prob (F-statistic):              0.803
Time:                        13:42:31   Log-Likelihood:                -4764.7
No. Observations:                1000   AIC:                             9533.
Df Residuals:                     998   BIC:                             9543.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         49.2696      1.840     26.774      0.000      45.658      52.881
x1             0.0079      0.032      0.250      0.803      -0.054       0.070
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      630.187   Durbin-Watson:                   2.023
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               58.502
Skew:                           0.054   Prob(JB):                     1.98e-13
Kurtosis:                       1.820   Cond. No.                         119.
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Unsurprisingly, the $R^2$ is 0, the constant is very close to the mean of our range and the x1 term is a high p-value.

Now if I do:

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(rv2[:,1],rv1)
Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.803742011784952, pvalue=0.4216415967859215)
```

If I'm not mistaken, the high p-value of the T-test says we fail to reject the null that the two random variables have the same mean, or for lay business people, they're the same.

I start with random data because the results with the random data makes sense to me and I can easily reconcile them.

Now let's take some real data. The data happens to be price forecasts for a single commodity but from two different forecasters. The forecast is the hourly price for delivery during that hour for a year.

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                     v1   R-squared:                       0.098
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.098
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     947.6
Date:                Thu, 27 Apr 2023   Prob (F-statistic):          1.15e-197
Time:                        13:54:54   Log-Likelihood:                -46785.
No. Observations:                8760   AIC:                         9.357e+04
Df Residuals:                    8758   BIC:                         9.359e+04
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    -38.6710      2.712    -14.260      0.000     -43.987     -33.355
v2             2.5122      0.082     30.783      0.000       2.352       2.672
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                    15615.843   Durbin-Watson:                   0.551
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):         13358851.473
Skew:                          13.107   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                     192.506   Cond. No.                         167.
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

The T-test between v1 and v2 are

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=18.47596253739749, pvalue=1.6810632200828115e-75)
```

The p-value of the t-test says that we reject the null that the two variables have the same mean.

The $R^2$ says that 9.8% of the variation in v1 can be explained by this model.

What I'm trying to do is describe, if any, the (colloquial) significance of the T-test saying they're different while there's, at least weakly, a linear relationship between the two. It's not hard to conceive that two variables can have different means but are still linearly related. Is there no good reason to use the t-test in this way?

If it helps, here's a scatter of `v1` and `v2`with the above trendline.

[image]

Comment: The issue in your final paragraph is not very clear. *"It's not hard to conceive that two variables can have different means but are still linearly related"* Obviously. Like the speed of a race car and the speed of a little motorbikes as function of the throttle, the two will be related but with large differences. ---- So what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

There are four possibilities.

1. Same mean, linearly related
2. Same mean, no linear relationship
3. Different mean, linearly related
4. Different mean, no linear relationship

Simulations of each of these are below.

```py
import numpy as np

# Define sample size
#
N = 100_000

# Same mean, linearly related
#
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)     # Mean of 0
y = x + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N) # Means add, so mean of 0

# Same mean, not linearly related
#
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N) # Mean of 0
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N) # Mean of 0, totally independent of x

# Different mean, linearly related
#
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)     # Mean of 0
y = x + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N) # Means add, so mean of 0

# Different mean, not linearly related
#
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N) # Mean of 0
y = np.random.uniform(0, 2, N)  # Mean of 1, totally independent of x
```

Thus, whether or not two variables have equal means is totally unrelated to their correlation or regression $R^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The use of a 2 independent samples t-test is not justified in this context, because the data is matched-pairs data.  So, from that perspective, the answer to the OP's question is:  No, there is not a good reason to use the t-test in this way (as it is not the correct test for the data).

However, if you ask about running a dependent-samples t-test and the correlation, then there is indeed a good rationale for this.  I'll give the example I use in my survey methodology course.  You have two raters, and you want to know that they rate the subjects in a similar fashion...and this means both (1) on average and (2) in relation to each other.

Let's think thru the 4 possible scenarios:

1. If the correlation is n.s. ($p > \alpha$) and the t-test is stat.sig. ($p < \alpha$), this is the worst case scenario.  The raters are rating the subjects differently (the means are not the same) and there is no relationship between when one rater rates the subjects high/low compared to the other rater. (bad situation)
2. If the correlation is stat.sig and the t-test is stat.sig., this is probably a workable case for assessment, as you could "curve" one of the raters to essentially match the other rater. (workable situation)
3. If the correlation is n.s. and the t-test is n.s., then this means the average of the ratings are essentially the same...but it means that it may be happening in a random or haphazard way as there is no relationship between the two raters' scores. (probably not good for an external validity argument for the rating of the construct being assessed)
4. If the correlation is stat.sig. and the t-test is n.s., then this means the averages are about the same, and the raters are relatively consistent in how they are rating each subject. (best scenario)

While I am not specifically seeing if---or how---this example may relate to the OP's scenario, it does demonstrate that there are times when you want to consider both the t-ratio and the correlation.

Hope this helps, and happy to clarify more if desired.

Comment: I imagine that raters are not gonna have a negative correlation easily, but in different settings a negative correlation might occur, and then the 4th case might be a situation where there is a significant correlation and the correlation interferes with the t-test (making a paired test less significant than an independent samples test).

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to mention that the correlation should be assessed for positive correlation.  Though, I guess one could argue that if there is a negative relation, that might be an indicator that the rater mis-read the valence anchors for the scale (mixing up disagree & agree :-)

Comment: In different settings the negative correlation might make more sense. It happens whenever we want to determine the difference in the mean of two quantities, and we take paired measurements, where within the pairs there is a negative influence. For example a cruiseschip wants to reduce their offer (e.g. in catering/bar) and might want to evaluate whether there is a difference between the amount of products A and B being sold, which were offered both at the same time during the last trips. The amounts of servings per cruise might be negatively correlated. More A could mean less B and vice versa.